# How can I use pgn-extract to remove a game from a pgn file when there is an illegal move?

Tags: illegal-move

How can I use pgn-extract to remove a game from a pgn file when there is an illegal move?

Answer (score 8):

[pgn-extract](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/~djb/pgn-extract/) will do exactly that if you give it an input file and say where you want the correct games to go. For instance:

```
pgn-extract --output clean.pgn games.pgn
```

will put only the valid games from `games.pgn` into `clean.pgn`, reporting any errors on standard output. If you want to have a record of the errors then you can use the -l flag to specify a log file; e.g.:

```
pgn-extract --output clean.pgn -lissues.txt games.pgn
```

There are lots of additional options/flags described in [the documentation](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/~djb/pgn-extract/help.html).

Disclosure: I am the author of pgn-extract.